# How to disable "unterminated statement" inspection in TypeScript modules without change JavaScript inspection (WebStorm)?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

In many similar questions, they give advice to completely disable this inspection in IDE, but this creates an equivalent new problem for JavaScript modules.

Is there any way to do this specifically for the TypeScript modules. Could it be the local configuration of the module or something else?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable inspection for specific code constructions only.
But you can suppress it for statement:

- Place the caret on problematic place and bring the *Quick Fix* menu (`Alt + Enter` or by clicking on light bulb icon)
- Choose the right option in appeared menu
- hit `Right` (or click on small triangle on the right side) to open submenu
- Choose **Suppress for statement**

Note that since 2017.1.x this inspection respects **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Punctuation** settings: if **Use semicolons** == *Do not use always*, inspection only highlights suspicious statements. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24627 for details